# VBA to copy and paste to a range of cells based on a date ( logical VBA Code)

Tags: vba, excel, copy, paste

I have a table which columns are represented by months in certain fiscal years.  Each month there are values that I run a query for and add in monthly.

I want the vba to copy and paste a Match index formula (which I already have) into a column of cells based on the month and fiscal year.

For example for April 2015 I would want the code to differentiate from the other months and just paste the formula in that column.

Comment: Just a little suggestion: use cells to evaluate formulae. e.g. cell("A1")="TODAY()" and then use the text to continue your evaluation.

Comment: The formulae are developed in a way they can be copied to other cells. I recommend getting help with the formula so it will be more universal. If you want your cascading error to show in the last month then you will need to fix the values in columns before and then apply a broader definition(SUMIFS?).